# Android Viewflipper, onConfigurationChanged method never called

Tags: android, android-tabhost, viewflipper

I am using ViewFlipper inside TabHost in my application.
I am not able to control the orientation. I have written following code in the manifest file:

```
activity android:name=".HomeActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

But still, the method `onConfigurationChanged` is never called in my activity.
When my orientation is changed, the activity is recreated and reloaded every time.

EDIT:
I found that ScreenSize is only applicable for api level above 11.
If I control the orientation change in lower sdk version like 2.3.3, it is not working in ICS and if I control the orientation change in ICS (providing ScreenSize), 2.3.3 is not working. How to make android orientation changes compatible to all the sdk versions?

Comment: Please show the code that you have included in manifest file. If I understood correctly your question, you are trying to do not recreate an activity when orientation changes, right?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to copy my code, <activity android:name=".HomeActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using targetSdkVersion < 11 therefore place in the manifest file

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

insetad of

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" , writing about code gives me Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden')

Comment: That should work. Have you tried clean a project after adding this line?

Comment: I cleaned project several times, but it doesnt work, and I think, configChanges = "ScreenSize" is only available for SDKversion > 11 and not SDKversion < 11